# Tag synonym suggestion: semantics <- semantic

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

[semantics](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/semantics) has 73 questions, [semantic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/semantic) has three.

Answer (score 5):

Tags synonymized and merged to [semantics](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/semantics).